# Получение данных ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Добрый вечер. Стараюсь вникнуть в технологию ajax. Пытался сделать выпадающий список, чтобы значения этого списка брались из таблицы. То есть value это id из таблицы, а сам текст - это поле name. Проблема в том, что php файл возвращает оба этих результата вместе и я не могу найти способ их разделить. Вопрос очень глупый, но решения найти так и не смог. 
Как разделить данные с ответа? И как разделить их в случае если это массив.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Код свой покажите, чего гадать-то.

Answer (score 0):

Если используется в запросе AJAX - ответ не может быть в виде массиве. Выходит - либо JSON либо stringify, а можно и свой написать. В основном, конечно же, используется технология JSON, то есть в PHP пишется что-то типа:

```
return json_encode($data)
```

На клиентской стороне, если используется jQuery - что-то типа этого

```
$.ajax({
   //Данные для AJAX запроса
}).done(function(result){  //функция заработает тогда, когда мы получим ответ от сервера
    //result содержит то, что написано в PHP выше
    result = JSON.parse(result); //получаем массив
    console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Да я именно так и сделал. А как теперь этот полученный массив разделить? То есть отдельно записать id и name

Comment: @Veliar есть много методов. for var in key , each и.т.д , непонятно что вы сделать хотите и в каком формате вам нужны данные на выходе. Формулируйте вопрос более развёрнуто.

Comment: Приведите пример кода PHP